# MigraDoc - Width Percentage

Tags: c#, migradoc

I am converting a current ITextSharp PDF Export to MigraDoc. it is a very table heavy PDF and a lot of use is made of `Table.WidthPercentage` which sets the width of `Table`. I am trying to replicate this in MigraDoc but so far have come up with nothing. I can probably do something manually but want to see if there was a better way of doing this?

EDIT

Now knowing that the MigraDoc Column widths are Absolute I am looking to apply the Width manually. In this particular instance I have a table that exists within a cell (as an element) of another table. I am therefore looking to capture the Column.Width of the parent table but it just keeps coming back empty? Is this not automatically set / calculated or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: If in doubt show some code. MigraDoc uses home-made nullable values (created in the days of .NET 1.1) and some values come back as 0 when they were not set and the default value will be used. Probably you have to explicitly set the width of the parent column if the child table depends on it. All MigraDoc document elements have a Tag member you can use for your purposes - the child table could use the Tag member of the parent table to get the information it needs.

Comment: I have amanged to get on top of all this now. Just a case of making sure I am setting widths in the correct places (i.e. not after I am trying to use them! haha). Thanks again, your answer below put me on the right path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tables in MigraDoc have absolute dimensions. You know the width of your pages and can calculate absolute widths from percentages when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply... In one example I have added a table to a cell which exists in another table. Am I easily able to apply a width to the child table that is say 100% of the cell it exists within? If you are able to provide any examples would be greatly appreciated.